# Count number of months till last month using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count number of months till last month where registeration is done.i wrote the query as

```
SELECT count(MONTH(`regdate`) < MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(`regdate`) <= YEAR(CURDATE())) FROM `client_details` WHERE hospitalid='apollo123'
```

Comment: You want to get the difference between the two dates?

Comment: no . I want to find in which all the month regstration is done and count that number of month registration..

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're asking as we don't know what your data looks like or what result you want. I _suspect_ you're confused about what the COUNT function does, but I really don't know for certain. Can you please [edit] your question to include sample data and results?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
select month(regdate), count(*)
  from client_details
  where regdate < curdate()
    and hospitalid = 'apollo123'
  group by month(regdate);
```

This will, for each month prior to `curdate()` give you the count of registrations that happened in that month.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count (*)from (
select month(regdate)
from client_details
where regdate < curdate()
and hospitalid = 'apollo123'
group by month(regdate));
```

This will give you number of months till last month when registrations were done.

Answer (score -2):

One solution is

```
select count(distinct(cast(MONTH(regdate) as nvarchar(10)) + cast(year(regdate) as nvarchar(10)))) from client_details where hospitalid = 'apollp123' and regdate < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
```

I tested this one on Sql Server, you should adjust the code for mySql .

Comment: This won't actually count the number of months but the number of unique rows (I.e. Dates), which don't seem to represent months. Plus, for some reason you're converting dates to characters, nvarchars (?) and you've done this in something that won't even work...

Comment: I've noted that I wrote it on SqlServer. 
Number of month (in character) + year(in character) is actually the number of month that he needs.
Hope it helps